# If both the union and the power set of a set are transitive, does the set have to transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $x$ is a set, and $\mathcal{P}x$ and $\cup x$ are both transitive sets, does $x$ necessarily have to be transitive?

Answer (score 2):

No. To find a counterexample, consider $x'$ which is transitive, and take $x=x'\setminus\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: Say, $x=\{1\}$. Then $\mathcal P(x)=\{0,x\}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind, but it works pretty much with any larger transitive set (not with smaller ones, though).